# UIScreen bounds versus applicationFrame

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscreen

Why do I see in some sample code from Apple (such as PhotoScroller) that I should do the following in `loadView`:

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

instead of

```
CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
```

Does it make a difference to get the main screen's frame?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

ApplicationFrame is the screen size minus the size of the status bar (if visible), bounds is the screen size regardless of status bar.

So applicationFrame would return `CGRectMake(0,0,320,460)` assuming your app has the status bar set to be visible, while bounds would return `CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)` under the same conditions. Those numbers are assuming iPhone/iPod Touch screen sizes.

[UIScreen Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html)

Comment: I might be mistaken, but doesn't applicationFrame return CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)? Where 20 is the offset of the status bar...

Comment: You're not mistaken, Niels :).  The y-offset will be reported as 20 with a status bar, not 0.

Comment: Hi @jamone, what if the Personal Hotspot is shown? It seems to be taking 20 points high (same as the status bar). Would applicationFrame return CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 440) on 3.5 inches iPhone and CGRectMake(0, 40, 320, 528) on 4 inches one?

Comment: @congliu That's right. on an iPhone 5, ApplicationFrame is usually (x=0, y=20, w=320, h=548) but when the Personal Hotspot or In Call Status Bar is present, this becomes (x=0, y=40, w=320, h=528)

Answer (score 2):

**iOS 9 Update**

When using the Split View feature on the iPad, `applicationFrame` returns the size of your app window. `bounds` always returns the size of the device.

Comment: `-applicationFrame` was **deprecated in iOS 9**