# How to set a UIView in fullscreen for all Device in iOS Programatically?

Tags: ios

I have to set an `UIView` in fullscreen Programatically for all devices like: iPhone 3GS, 4, 4S, 5, 5S, 5C.

I googled so many times and get a answer but its not coming properly. 20 pixel is less from bottom part. I share my screenshot please see and let me know what i have to do.

[image]

My Code is :

```
      UIView  *myview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,   [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame].size.height)];
      [myview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
      [self.view addSubview: myview];
```

See properly from bottom its 20 pixel is white. How can i manage that. ?

Comment: "ApplicationFrame is the screen size minus the size of the status bar (if visible), bounds is the screen size regardless of status bar." : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3120139/2791407

Comment: Are you using autolayout or not ?

Comment: Then you have to use autolayout or add +20 on view height ,because your status bar is overlapping on view.

Comment: I am creating through coding not using XIB or Storyboard

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this one:

```
 UIView  *myview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
 [myview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
 [self.view addSubview:myview];
```

I'll clarify you properly, i think you can understand.

It's a little bit difference in between **[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]** & **[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]**.

When you take `UIScreen` for it's Bounds you get the whole device screen. (include status bar).There is no relationship between the two calls except that the `applicationFrame` is returned in the `UIScreen` bounds coordinate system.

Comment: This will make the new view full-screen in terms of _size_, but it will position it respective to the top-left corner of `self.view`, which **may not be the top-left corner of the screen**.

Comment: Could someone show the swift equivalent for this one?

Answer (score 1):

```
UIView  *myview = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
[myview setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
[self.window addSubview: myview];

 NSLog(@"FRAME: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(myview.bounds));
```

> 2014-09-11 12:17:37.451 Test[21793:60b] FRAME: {{0, 0}, {320, 480}}