# Usage of CGrect for positioning button in objective c frame view bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to position the button on uiimageview in uicollectionview  .

```
_prevButton.frame =  CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.height, 50, 30);
```

How i can use this (self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.height) to set button width and height ?I am pretty new in objective c .How i can comprehend it to use for button sizing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [bounds versus applicationFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120139/bounds-versus-applicationframe)

Comment: no i want definition  and usage of these terms.... self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.height

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this for clear understanding.

[image]

Comment: self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.size.height...please explain these terms

Comment: see viewB frame and its bounds in image. then u could understand it